# How do I read the UID of a tag (e.g. Mifare Classic) using the ACR122U Reader and PCSC library in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, nfc, acr122

Right so I have the following code that works fine using the [PCSC-sharp Iso7816 Library](https://github.com/danm-de/pcsc-sharp):

```
Imports PCSC
Imports PCSC.Iso7816
Imports PCSC.Utils
Imports System


Public Class TapMembershipCard

    Dim MembershipCardUID As String

    Sub ReadCard() Handles ReadCardBtn.Click
        Using context = New SCardContext()
            context.Establish(SCardScope.System)

            Dim readerNames = context.GetReaders()
            Dim sc As PCSC.SCardError

            Dim readerName = readerNames.FirstOrDefault()
            If readerName Is Nothing Then
                Return
            End If

            Using rfidReader = New SCardReader(context)
                sc = rfidReader.Connect(readerName, SCardShareMode.Shared, SCardProtocol.Any)
                If sc <> SCardError.Success Then
                    'THIS IS USUALLY WHERE THE PROGRAM WILL GET TO IF NO CARD HAS BEEN PRESENTED
                    Return
                End If

                PresentCard.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden

                Dim apdu = New CommandApdu(IsoCase.Case2Short, rfidReader.ActiveProtocol) With {
                    .CLA = &HFF,
                    .Instruction = InstructionCode.GetData,
                    .P1 = &H0,
                    .P2 = &H0,
                    .Le = 7
                }

                sc = rfidReader.BeginTransaction()
                If sc <> SCardError.Success Then
                    Console.WriteLine("Could not begin transaction.")
                    Return
                End If

                Console.WriteLine("Retrieving the UID .... ")

                Dim receivePci = New SCardPCI() ' IO returned protocol control information.
                Dim sendPci = SCardPCI.GetPci(rfidReader.ActiveProtocol)

                Dim receiveBuffer = New Byte(255) {}
                Dim command = apdu.ToArray()

                sc = rfidReader.Transmit(sendPci, command, receivePci, receiveBuffer)
                If sc <> SCardError.Success Then
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " & SCardHelper.StringifyError(sc))
                End If

                Dim responseApdu = New ResponseApdu(receiveBuffer, IsoCase.Case2Short, rfidReader.ActiveProtocol)
                Console.Write("SW1: {0:X2}, SW2: {1:X2}" & vbCrLf & "Uid: {2}", responseApdu.SW1, responseApdu.SW2, If(responseApdu.HasData, BitConverter.ToString(responseApdu.GetData()), "No uid received"))

                rfidReader.EndTransaction(SCardReaderDisposition.Leave)
                rfidReader.Disconnect(SCardReaderDisposition.Reset)

                MembershipCardUID = BitConverter.ToString(responseApdu.GetData())
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

But ideally I would like to have it so that it constantly checks if a card is present instead of having to click the button once a card is presented. Also, can it be simplified in any way? I feel as though its a lot of code for just reading the UID.

**I am willing to use any libraries or frameworks that are compatible with VB.net and also I'm happy for any ideas to be written in C# if it's preferred.**
FYI I'm using .NET 8.0 WPF Application. [The reader is an ACR122U reader](http://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/3/acr122u-usb-nfc-reader/)

I have tried to simply use recursion or call the sub again from within this IF statement:

```
sc = rfidReader.Connect(readerName, SCardShareMode.Shared, SCardProtocol.Any)
If sc <> SCardError.Success Then
    'THIS IS USUALLY WHERE THE PROGRAM WILL GET TO IF NO CARD HAS BEEN PRESENTED
    Return
End If
```

The issue is that none of the visual elements load / everything will freeze whilst it is constantly iterating until a card is presented.

Ideally I would like to be able to have some code that detects when a card is presented, then sends the ADPU command to retrieve the UID.

Comment: Can you link the "PCSC library"? That does not sound like an obvious thing to me.

Comment: @Ralf My apologies. Completely forgot! The library is the PCSC-sharp library https://github.com/danm-de/pcsc-sharp specifically Iso7816

Comment: That library seems to have surface such functionality via MonitorEvents. [This](https://github.com/danm-de/pcsc-sharp/blob/master/Examples/MonitorReaderEvents/Program.cs) example shows how to react to the Inserted/Removed Events. Presumably what you need, waiting for the Card to be inserted.

Comment: I cant believe I missed that, I was spending all my time looking in the ISO7816 demos. Now to figure out how to convert it and integrate it into my code, though this sounds like the solution!

Comment: @Ralf the code works well, it even gets me the uid of the cards so i wont even be using any of my old code. Trouble is that it still has the same problem in that it doesnt let the ui elements load in the window. I need a way to delay the initialization of the code by a few milliseconds.

Comment: Then have a look at the WPF specific [example](https://github.com/danm-de/pcsc-sharp/blob/master/Examples.Wpf/RxMonitorReaderEventsWpf/MainWindowViewModel.cs) that go at it a bit different. Maybe it handles that case better even if it looks a bit to complicated to me with the reactive stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [ACR122U Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NFC-ACR122U/) Here's the documentation: [Github](https://github.com/sydesoft/Sydesoft.NfcDevice.ACR122U) + [Website](https://www.sydesoft-blog.de/nfc-reader-acr122u.html). It doesn't seem to be maintained but it is very helpful. Here's the code I ended up using (It is by no means perfect, its a work in progress. I have just managed to get the following working):

```
Imports System
Imports PCSC
Imports PCSC.Iso7816
Imports PCSC.Monitoring


Public Class TapMembershipCard

    Private maxReadWriteLength As Integer = 50
    Private blockSize As Integer = 4
    Private startBlock As Integer = 4
    Private readbackDelayMilliseconds As Integer = 100
    Private cardReaderNames As String() = Nothing
    Private cardContext As ISCardContext = Nothing
    Private buzzerSet As Boolean = False
    Private buzzerOnOff As Boolean = False

    Public Event CardInserted As CardInsertedHandler
    Public Delegate Sub CardInsertedHandler(reader As ICardReader)

    Public Event CardRemoved As CardRemovedHandler
    Public Delegate Sub CardRemovedHandler()


    Public Sub Init()
        buzzerOnOff = True
        maxReadWriteLength = 16
        blockSize = 16
        startBlock = 0
        readbackDelayMilliseconds = 10

        cardContext = ContextFactory.Instance.Establish(SCardScope.System)

        cardReaderNames = cardContext.GetReaders()

        Dim monitor = MonitorFactory.Instance.Create(SCardScope.System)
        AddHandler monitor.CardInserted, AddressOf Monitor_CardInserted
        AddHandler monitor.CardRemoved, AddressOf Monitor_CardRemoved
        monitor.Start(cardReaderNames)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Monitor_CardInserted(sender As Object, e As CardStatusEventArgs)
        Dim reader As ICardReader = Nothing

        Try
            reader = cardContext.ConnectReader(cardReaderNames(0), SCardShareMode.Shared, SCardProtocol.Any)
        Catch
        End Try

        If reader IsNot Nothing Then
            If Not buzzerSet Then
                buzzerSet = True
                SetBuzzer(reader, buzzerOnOff)
            End If

            RaiseEvent CardInserted(reader)
            GetUID(reader)

            Try
                reader.Disconnect(SCardReaderDisposition.Leave)
            Catch
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub SetBuzzer(reader As ICardReader, [on] As Boolean)
        Dim ret As Byte() = New Byte(1) {}

        reader.Transmit(New Byte() {&HFF, &H0, &H52, If([on], &HFF, &H0), &H0}, ret)
    End Sub


    Private Sub Monitor_CardRemoved(sender As Object, e As CardStatusEventArgs)
        RaiseEvent CardRemoved()
    End Sub

    Public Sub GetUID(reader As ICardReader)
        Dim uid As Byte() = New Byte(9) {}

        reader.Transmit(New Byte() {&HFF, &HCA, &H0, &H0, &H0}, uid)

        Array.Resize(uid, 7)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It seems that you are using the Mifare Classic card as "membership" card, but you already know that the 4-byte UID is no longer "unique" ? Second: there are very cheap "CUID" card on the market that easy allow to change the UID to an individual one, so with this knowledge it is very easy to create a perfect clone of the original card. Third: the encryption algorithm on Mifare Classic tags ("Crypto-1") is broken since dekades - you should no longer rely on these tags.

Comment: It does actually get the 7byte UID instead of the 4 byte one, in fact I can specify how many bytes to get which was a requirement of the code. With your regards with being able to easily clone the cards, thanks for pointing it out, I wouldve been slightly concerned if i wasn't already aware (I clone them myself for the purpose of having backups in case i leave my main one a home). The boss decided they wanted either mifare classic or rfid for the purpose of it being as cheap as possible. Would you recommend RFID over mifare classic just out of curiosity as the reader supports both?

Comment: "RFID" is a general naming of the technology, but I think you mean tags based on 125 KHz frequency range (Mifare Classic and others operate in 13 MFz band) ? I do not have any experience in reading these tags, but as far as I can remember I read that those tags are very cheap again and there are copyable as well. The only chance for a real secure system would be the usage of tags based on AES technology (like Mifare DESFire EV2/EV3 tags, but they are in range of 2 Euros per tag).